# How to write a front-end interface for Markdown editing in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markdown

I have used Redcarpet to interpret Markdown, but use the normal Form to type Markdown.

I want a form that when I type the Markdown syntax in Form, it will highlight the text.

I have tried many thins but not work. I'm not familiar with Javascript, only know a little syntax.

Could anyone give a code example ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be interested in something such as [`markituUp! Rails`](https://github.com/phlipper/markitup-rails)

What you're basically looking for is a `wysiwyg` editor for markdown (like StackOverflow's editor). The important thing to note is this type of editor needs to be able to process inputs (selecting `bold | italic | underline` etc), and translating them to Rails

---

**Javascript**

In reference to javascript, JS is just a wrapper for HTML elements

All the WYSIWYG editors out there are just a way to "decorate" your HTML `text_area` inputs, allowing you to assign different commands to the input. For example, a WYSIWYG "bold" button will just input `**your_text**` around your selected text

Hope this helps?